# Is it possible to define a function in Haskell that has an input argument of two possible types?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, parametric-polymorphism

For my own understanding, I want to define a function in Haskell that takes two arguments- either both Integers, or both Chars. It does some trivial examination of the arguments, like so:

```
foo 1 2 = 1
foo 2 1 = 0
foo 'a' 'b' = -1
foo _ _ = -10
```

This I know won't compile, because it doesn't know whether its args are of type Num or Char. But I can't make its arguments polymorphic, like:

```
foo :: a -> a -> Int
```

Because then we are saying it must be a Char (or Int) in the body.

Is it possible to do this in Haskell? I thought of maybe creating a custom type? Something like:

```
data Bar = Int | Char
foo :: Bar -> Bar -> Int
```

But I don't think this is valid either. In general, I'm confused about if there's a middle ground between a function in Haskell being either explicitly of ONE type, or polymorphic to a typeclass, prohibiting any usage of a specific type in the function body.

Comment: Do both of the arguments have to be of the same type (in other words, can you pass it a `char` and an `int`)?

Comment: @ArthurLaks Both options are valid, I was specifically considering the case where you know they will be of the same type, but I think for learning purposes seeing either one would be valuable.

Comment: "Polymorphic to a typeclass" does not "prohibit any usage of a specific type in the function body"!

Comment: @DanielWagner 
buux :: [a] -> Int, buux [1] = 0, buux _ = -1. This does not compile- this is what I meant. We can't test that the contents of the list is an Int if we specified it as a polymorphic type, right?

Comment: @user2666425 Why would you want to check whether a list was [1] but yet not know the type of the list? What are you planning on putting in this list?

Comment: @AndrewC Another contrived situation to better understand Haskell that I posted over a year ago about- if I wanted a function that took a list of *anything*, am I not allowed to test whether it is first a list of an integer and do something special?

Comment: @user2666425 You can do something similar, but it's rarely useful. For example, `Typeable` is available for almost all types and offers the `typeOf` operation.

Comment: @user2666425 Also, re: "if I wanted a function that took a list of anything, am I not allowed to test whether it is first a list of an integer and do something special?": that is correct. This property generally goes by the name [parametricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity).

Comment: @DanielWagner Very fascinating. That is one of the most helpful links/responses I've had on SE. In particular, it led me to: [this page](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/introduction-to-haskell/5-type-classes), which described parametricity in Haskell and mentioned examples of what I posted about. The only thing I am still confused about is your mentioning of 'typeOf'. My above link mentions that there is no 'instance Of' equivalent in Haskell- types are erased at run time. What use is typeOf, or how is it different from instanceOf then?

Comment: @user2666425 I started typing an explanation of how it works and what it's good for, but that's much too big for a comment. Suffice it to say that there are certain cases where keeping type information at runtime is desirable, and this can be done manually by defining a new type that represents the information of interest. `Typeable` does this. This is useful when runtime type-checking is desirable. You might also be interested in looking at `Dynamic`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
type Bar = Either Int Char

foo :: Bar -> Bar -> Int
foo (Left 1) (Left 2) = 1
foo (Right 'a') (Right 'b') = -1 
foo (Left 3) (Right 'q') = 42
foo _ _ = 10
```

and things like that - the `Either` data type is precisely for mixing two types together. You can roll your own similar type like

```
data Quux = AnInt Int | AChar Char | ThreeBools Bool Bool Bool
```

It's called an Algebraic Data Type.

(I struggle to think of circumstances when it's useful to mix specifically characters and integers together - mainly it's very helpful to know where your data is and what type it is.)

That said, I write algebraic data types a lot, but I give them meaningful names that represent actual things rather than just putting random stuff together because I don't like to be specific. Being very specific or completely general is useful. In between there are typeclasses like `Eq`. You can have a function with type `Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool` which means it has type `a -> [a] -> Bool` for any type that has `==` defined, and I leave it open for people to use it for data types I never thought of as long as they define an equality function.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Learning about algebraic data types helped me figure out a way to do this. My only question then is if you can hide from the person calling the function that an ADT is involved- For instance, if I'd rather them just call the function like foo 'a' 'b' rather than foo (AChar 'a') (AChar 'b'). Is it possible to abstract that detail of the implementation away from the function caller?

Comment: @user2666425 I think the tags keep us honest and explicit for sum types, and handily can be used in pattern matching, but if the syntax is getting you down, shorten the tags or use [Daniel Wagner's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27643670/1598537). I think it depends on your actual use case what the best approach is.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Either` data type to store two different types. Something like this should work:

```
foo :: Either (Int, Int) (Char, Char) -> Int
foo (Right x) = 3
foo (Left y) = fst y
```

So, for it's `Left` data constructor you pass two `Int` to it and for it's `Right` constructor you pass two `Char` to it. Another way would be to define your own algebric data type like this:

```
data MyIntChar = MyInt (Int, Int) | MyChar (Char, Char) deriving (Show)
```

If you observe, then you can see that the above type is isomorphic to `Either` data type.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I would necessarily recommend using typeclasses for this, but they do make something like this possible at least.

```
class Foo a where
    foo :: a -> a -> Int

instance Foo Int where
    foo 1 2 = 1
    foo 2 1 = 0
    foo _ _ = -10

instance Foo Char where
    foo 'a' 'b' = -1
    foo _ _ = -10
```

Comment: I've come back to this answer after I've learned more about defining your own type classes and declaring a type to be an instance of a typeclass in Haskell- but I'm still not sure how to *use* what you've written here. I know you create a typeclass `Foo` and then declare `Int` and `Char` to be instances of `Foo`. But how can we use it? - E.g. `foo 2 5` errors out, as does any other attempt to call `foo`. `foo` is defined in ghci, and has signature `foo :: Foo a => a -> a -> Int`. So how can I actually get a `foo`? `2 :: Foo` -> `Expecting one more argument to Foo`.

Comment: @user2666425 `foo (2 :: Int) 5` will do. Recall that `2` has many types.

Comment: Doesn't Haskell normally handle the conversion of `2` to whatever instance of `Num` is needed? Like in `bar x = x + 1.0; bar 2`, it converts it automatically. Why do we need to convert it to an `Int` manually?

Comment: @user2666425 There is no conversion, ever. It just has many possible types. When it isn't sure which of many possible types to choose, you must give it some guidance.

Comment: Conversion was the wrong word, but in `bar` it knows it needs to be `Fractional`, and as there is only a definition for `Foo Int`, not `Foo Integer`, etc, I'm just confused why it doesn't know itself what type to make `2`.

Comment: @user2666425 There are some built-in defaulting rules for common numerical classes, but no rules (and no way to define any) for custom classes like those you write yourself. See [the relevant section of the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4) for details.